# Python: how to use re{n}

Tags: regex, python-3.x

The following regular expression repeats the same pattern 16 times:

```
\d[\s|-]*\d[\s|-]*\d[\s|-]*\d[\s|-]*\d[\s|-]*\d[\s|-]*\d[\s|-]*\d[\s|-]*\d[\s|-]*\d[\s|-]*\d[\s|-]*\d[\s|-]*\d[\s|-]*\d[\s|-]*\d[\s|-]*\d[\s|-]*
```

I tried to simplify it by using:

```
[d[\s|-]*]{16}
```

But it doesn't work. What was found by the previous expression is not found by the second one. By the way, strictly speaking what I need is to use re{16,}, to find 16 or more digits regardless of being separated by space or hyphen.

Note that I'm not very experienced. I did make some searches and tests but haven't found an answer. So apologies for the basic question.

Comment: Using group: `(\d[\s|-]*){16}`, using non-capturing group: `(?:\d[\s|-]*){16}`

Comment: Your second suggestion works, but not the first, which only finds one digit. What's the difference?

Comment: It depends on what function/method you're using. Please search for capturing group, non-capturing group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place the range operator after a grouping construct.

```
(?:\d[\s-]*){16}
```

**Explanation**:

```
(?:        # group, but do not capture (16 times):
  \d       #   digits (0-9)
  [\s-]*   #   any character of: whitespace, '-' (0 or more times)
){16}      # end of grouping
```

**Note:** `|` inside a character class is not an alternation operator, it matches the character literally.

Comment: Yes that works. Using "grouping construct instead of a character class". In the same line of thought, perhaps I shouldn't have used the character class to indicate "space or hyphen". This would be more correct (?:\d(?:\s|-)*){16} ?

Comment: No, the character class would be more efficient